# Factorygirl skipping an attribute on create when value is present in factory and non-null field in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Factory:

```
factory :company do
    name                    { Faker::Company.name }
    about                   { Faker::Company.catch_phrase() }
    employees_count         1
    creator_employer_id     1
    address                 { Faker::Address.street_address }
    city                    { Faker::Address.city }
    state                   { Faker::Address.state_abbr }
    zip                     { Faker::Address.zip_code }
    public_profile          true
  end
```

In Sandbox:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:company)
D, [2015-05-25T12:22:56.091472 #19306] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
D, [2015-05-25T12:22:56.095934 #19306] DEBUG -- :   SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("about", "address", "city", "employees_count", "name", "public_profile", "state", "zip") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["about", "Balanced multi-tasking help-desk"], ["address", "9074 Doyle Road"], ["city", "Spinkamouth"], ["employees_count", 1], ["name", "Reynolds-Jacobs"], ["public_profile", "t"], ["state", "DE"], ["zip", "20779"]]
E, [2015-05-25T12:22:56.096058 #19306] ERROR -- : PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "creator_employer_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Note the INSERT excludes the value of 1 from the factory.

```
FactoryGirl.create(:company, creator_employer_id: 1)
D, [2015-05-25T12:23:58.369059 #19306] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
D, [2015-05-25T12:23:58.372071 #19306] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("about", "address", "city", "creator_employer_id", "employees_count", "name", "public_profile", "state", "zip") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["about", "Total exuding database"], ["address", "851 Alayna Overpass"], ["city", "Kleinville"], ["creator_employer_id", 1], ["employees_count", 1], ["name", "Schoen, Rohan and Wunsch"], ["public_profile", "t"], ["state", "TN"], ["zip", "97480"]]
D, [2015-05-25T12:23:58.373378 #19306] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => #<Company id: 106, name: "Schoen, Rohan and Wunsch", logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, about: "Total exuding database", employees_count: 1, address: "851 Alayna Overpass", city: "Kleinville", state: "TN", zip: "97480", public_profile: true, website: nil, creator_employer_id: 1>
```

This succeeds when the value is explicitly set.

Why is FactoryGirl ignoring this field in my factory when not explicitly setting it?  public_profile and employees_count fields are NOT NULL in db but have a default value.  creator_employer_id is NOT NULL and is set create

UPDATE: When using the sandbox console, I receive the error when using FactoryGirl.create :company but after entering FactoryGirl.reload, the same command works properly.  This feels like a bug.

Comment: Do you have any code that calculates/modifies `creator_employer_id` before save? In a callback perhaps?

Comment: Nope, no callbacks nor validations in the model for the field

Comment: I wound up changing the implementation of the ownership to avoid spinning my wheels too much on this issue

Comment: Having this same issue in JRuby 1.7.21 FactoryGirl 4.5.0. Another workaround is having a before(:create) in the factory